# Numpy array change value

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code and I don't get why the array only changes the first time:

```
a = numpy.zeros(10)
old = 0

for i in range(100):
    if i % 10 == 5:
        new = input('New value of array entries?')
        for xi in range(10):
            if a[xi] == old:
                a[xi] = new
        old = new
        print(a)
```

Output:

```
New value of array entries?2
[ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
New value of array entries?1
[ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
New value of array entries?3
[ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
```

Edit: The problem was solved by @Jean-François Fabre in the comments. Apparently in Python 3 input returns a string.

Comment: python 2 or 3 ? because in python 3 `input` returns a string.

Comment: Python 3, so thats the problem :D ... Thanks!